# Program Multiple Input Neural Network Architecture with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I want to program a neural network and I'm using the Keras library for it. One dataset is divided into a random number of subsets (1-100). Not used subsets are set to zero. One subset consists of 2*4+1 binary input values. The Architecture should look like this (The weights of all subset networks should be shared):

```
.   InA1(4) InB1(4)   _
.       \     /        \
.     FCNA  FCNB       |
.         \ /          |
.      Concatinate     |
.          |           \ 100x (InA2, InB2, InC2, InA3, ...)
.         FCN          /
.InC(1)    |           |
.     \   /            |
.      \ /            _/
.  Concatinate
.       |
.      FCN
.       |
.     Out(1)
```

I have looked through a number of tutorials and examples but I dont find a proper method to implement that network. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from keras import *

# define arrays for training set input
InA = []
InB = []
InC = []
for i in range(100):
    InA.append( Input(shape=4,), dtype='int32') )
    InB.append( Input(shape=4,), dtype='int32') )
    InC.append( Input(shape=1,), dtype='int32') )

NetA = Sequential()
NetA.add(Dense(4, input_shape(4,), activation="relu"))
NetA.add(Dense(3, activation="relu"))

NetB = Sequential()
NetB.add(Dense(4, input_shape(4,), activation="relu"))
NetB.add(Dense(3, activation="relu"))

NetMergeAB = Sequential()
NetMergeAB.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,2), activation="relu"))

# merging all subsample networks of InA, InB
MergeList = []
for i in range(100):
    NetConcat = Concatenate()( [NetA(InA[i]), NetB(InB[i])] )
    MergedNode = NetMergeAB(NetConcat)
    MergeList.append(MergedNode)
    MergeList.append(InC[i])

# merging also InC
FullConcat = Concatenate()(MergeList)

# put in fully connected net
ConcatNet = Sequential()
ConcatNet.add(Dense(10, input_shape(2, 100), activation="relu"))
ConcatNet.add(Dense(6, activation="relu"))
ConcatNet.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
ConcatNet.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))

Output = ConcatNet(FullConcat)
```

The problem is, that either I get a "no Tensor" error, or it doesnt work at all. Has someone a idea how to solve this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from the answer of the question author:

```
ActInA = Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32')
ActInB = Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32')
ActInC = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

NetA = Dense(4, activation="relu")(ActInA)
NetA = Dense(3, activation="relu")(NetA)

NetB = Dense(4, activation="relu")(ActInB)
NetB = Dense(3, activation="relu")(NetB)

NetAB = concatenate([NetA, NetB])
NetAB = Dense(1, activation="relu")(NetAB)
```

Now we build a model for this subset of the net:

```
mymodel = Model([ActInA, ActInB], NetAB)
```

Now the important part from the [keras doc](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

> All models are callable, just like layers

this means you can simpy do something like this:

```
for i in range(100):
   NetMergeABC.append(mymodel([ActInA_array[i], ActInB_array[i]]))
```

Because you reuse the layers, the weights will be shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that network architecture easily with the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) and not use `Sequential` at all:

```
InA, InB, InC = [Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32') for _ in range(3)]

netA = Dense(4, activation="relu")(InA)
netA = Dense(3, activation="relu")(netA)

netB = Dense(4, activation="relu")(InB)
netB = Dense(3, activation="relu")(netB)

netMergeAB = concatenate([netA, netB])
netMergeAB = Dense(1, activation="relu")(netMergeAB)

fullConcat = concatenate([netMergeAB, InC])

out = Dense(10, activation="relu")(fullConcat)
out = Dense(6, activation="relu")(out)
out = Dense(4, activation="relu")(out)
out = Dense(1, activation="relu")(out)

model = Model([InA, InB, InC], out)
```

You might need to adjust it slightly but the overall idea should be clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code works, but its not quite what I need, because there is only one netA, B and C.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code and I hope that it is more clear now:

```
NetMergeABC = []
for i in range(100):
    ActInA = Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32')
    ActInB = Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32')
    ActInC = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

    NetA = Dense(4, activation="relu")(ActInA)
    NetA = Dense(3, activation="relu")(NetA)

    NetB = Dense(4, activation="relu")(ActInB)
    NetB = Dense(3, activation="relu")(NetB)

    NetAB = concatenate([NetA, NetB])
    NetAB = Dense(1, activation="relu")(NetAB)
    NetMergeABC.append(NetAB)
    NetMergeABC.append(ActInC)

NetABC = concatenate(NetMergeABC)
NetABC = Dense(10, activation="relu")(NetABC)
NetABC = Dense(6, activation="relu")(NetABC)
NetABC = Dense(4, activation="relu")(NetABC)
NetABC = Dense(1, activation="relu")(NetABC)
```

The problem now is, that (I guess) the weights of the NetA/B/C 1-100 arent shared.

Comment: Ok, I have found the solution: Take the code above and create a sequential model of NetA, NetB and NetMergeAB before the loop. In the loop then call the sequential models instead of make new dense layers.